# Counting the most common in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select the description of the most common delivery type but I am not 100 % sure how to do this.

I tried doing this but it is giving me the wrong results.

```
select Description
from DeliveryType
group by Description
having count(*) > all (select count (*) from DeliveryType group by DeliveryTypeID)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Are you sure that there is not another table involved in this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you are pretty close.  I think you want `>=` and to fix the aggregation columns.  The following returns the id with the description:

```
Select DeliveryTypeID, max(Description)
from DeliveryType
group by DeliveryTypeID
having count(*) >= all (Select count (*)
                        from DeliveryType
                        group by DeliveryTypeID
                       );
```

Although this should return a result, I don't think it is useful.  In a table called `DeliveryType`, the `DeliveryTypeID` should be unique (actually, the primary key).  Hence the counts should all be `1`.